# How to make a div flip on button press?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a div flip once a button has been clicked, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly and I can't figure out why. I was wondering if anybody would be able to point me in the right direction and correct my errors.

**My code:**

```js
var init = function() {
  var card = document.getElementById('card');

  document.getElementById('flip').addEventListener('click', function() {
    card.toggleClassName('flipped');
  }, false);
};

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 800px;
}
#card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
}
#card figure {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
#card .front {
  background: red;
}
#card .back {
  background: blue;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
#card.flipped {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div id="card">
    <figure class="front">1</figure>
    <figure class="back">2</figure>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="options">
  <p>
    <button id="flip">Flip Card</button>
  </p>
</section>
```

You can find a JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/scf0ma4c/3/).

Thank you.

Comment: Hey @junoprobelaunch, if you found a solution that worked for you, please mark the answer as "accepted" to help out the rest of the community. Thanks! `^_^`

Answer (score 3):

There were two things keeping your code from running:

1. JSFiddle runs JavaScript in `onLoad` by default, which is after the `DOMContentLoaded` event that you're waiting for, so remove that for the purposes of the JSFiddle only.
2. There is no `toggleClassName` function in vanilla JavaScript to the best of my knowledge. Instead I've changed it to toggle using the class list.

Here is the fixed and working code. I've shortened the box's height so it fits better in the demo box.

**Live Demo:**

```js
var card = document.getElementById('card');

document.getElementById('flip').addEventListener('click', function() {
    card.classList.toggle('flipped');
}, false);
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 800px;
}

#card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

#card figure {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#card .front {
  background: red;
}

#card .back {
  background: blue;
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

#card.flipped {
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div id="card">
    <figure class="front">1</figure>
    <figure class="back">2</figure>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="options">
  <p>
    <button id="flip">Flip Card</button>
  </p>
</section>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/dL9v1ozf/2/

Answer (score 3):

The below snippet will fix your problem.

**Finding out what's wrong**

- The console and `console.log` are your friends. If you add `console.log('clicked me')` or `alert('hi')` to your code inside the `click` event, you'll see nothing happens. So if the `click` event doesn't fire, what is wrong?
- Removing the `DOMContentLoaded` makes the click event work! ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tituswoo/scf0ma4c/7/)). If you open the console, you can see an error: `Uncaught TypeError: card.toggleClassName is not a function`. That's because `toggleClassName` isn't a valid method name.
- Use the `classList.toggle()` method instead of `toggleClassName()`
- Clean things up by making some variables with human readable names (e.g., `card` for the `#card` element, and `flipBtn` for the `#flip` button)

**Working demo:**

```js
(function() {
  var card = document.querySelector('#card');
  var flipBtn = document.querySelector('#flip');
  flipBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    card.classList.toggle('flipped');
  });
})();
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 800px;
}

#card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
  color: white;
}

#card figure {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#card .front {
  background: red;
}

#card .back {
  background: blue;
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}

#card.flipped {
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div id="card">
    <figure class="front">1</figure>
    <figure class="back">2</figure>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="options">
  <p>
    <button id="flip">Flip Card</button>
  </p>
</section>
```

**Some final thoughts**

- A lot of sandbox sites (like jsbin and jsfiddle) already wrap all the JavaScript code with `window.onload` as a convenience for you.
- So, if you're writing JS in a sandbox, don't use `window.onload` or `DOMContentLoaded` because it has already fired by the time the browser gets to your code. Hence, your code will never run.
- In a non-sandbox environment, make sure you either call the above JavaScript snippet after the page is loaded, or put it at the very bottom of the page (before the closing `body` tag).

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var card = document.querySelector('#card');
  var flipBtn = document.querySelector('#flip');
  flipBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    card.classList.toggle('flipped');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/scf0ma4c/5/ as your code was a little bit off.

In pure JavaScript, instead of using:

```
card.toggleClassName('flipped');
```

which doesn't exist at all you should use:

```
+=card.className
```

If you use jQuery:

```
$("#card").toggleClass("flipped");
```

makes it easier.

I believe using:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```

is completely purposeless since you want the flip to occur on click, so I removed it.

Check out the fiddle for more there.